# How to serialize Dataset to binary file/parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

How should I serialize a `DataSet`? Is there a way to use the `Encoder` to create a binary file, or should I convert it to a `DataFrame` and then save it as parquet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I serialize a DataSet?

```
dataset.toDF().write.parquet("")
```

I believe it would adhere to the schema that is being used by the dataset automatically.

> Is there a way to use the Encoder to create a binary file

Based on the source code of `Encoder` (for 1.6.0), it is designed to convert an input datasource into Dataset (to and from `InternalRow` to be precise but that's a very low-level detail). The default implementation matches every column from a dataframe into a case-class (for scala) or tuple or primitive so as to generate a Dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Java or Scala, right? Because PySpark doesn't have support for `Dataset` yet. In my experience the best you can do is to save your data as `parquet` file in `HDFS`, because I have noticed that the time required to read the file gets reduced comparing it with other formats like `csv` and others.

Sorry for my digression, but I thought it was important. As you can see in the documentation of [Dataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) class, you can't notice any method to save the data, therefore my suggestion is to use [toDF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) method from `Dataset` and then using [write](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method from `DataFrame`. Or also use the [DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) final class, using the `parquet` method.